# Rewrite Intel-style assembly code into GCC inline assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, operating-system, dos, interrupt

How to write this assembly code as inline assembly?     Compiler: gcc(i586-elf-gcc). The GAS syntax confuses me. **Please give tell me how to write this as inline assembly that works for gcc.**

```
.set_video_mode:
    mov ah,00h
    mov al,13h
    int 10h   

.init_mouse:
    mov ax,0
    int 33h
```

Similar one I have in assembly. I wrote them separate as assembly routines to call them from my C program. I need to call these and some more interrupts from C itself.

Also I need to put some values in some registers depending on which interrupt routine I'm calling. Please tell me how to do it.

**All that I want to do is call interrupt routines from C. It's OK for me even to do it using int86()** but i don't have source code of that function.
I want int86() so that i can call interrupts from C.

**I am developing my own tiny OS so i got no restrictions for calling interrupts or for any direct hardware access.**

Comment: erm... unless you use gcc to compile a kernel in ELF format (you still need a bootloader then), this isn't going to fly, because any OS granting direct access to the BIOS interrupts (e.g. MSDOS) aren't going to be able to run your binary

Comment: So this is basically a syntax question?

Comment: I see another problem: You want your code to be executed in real mode (16 bit), where gcc and gas will generate 32 bit code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested this, but it should get you started:

```
void set_video_mode (int x, int y) {
  register int ah asm ("ah") = x;
  register int al asm ("al") = y;

  asm volatile ("int $0x10"
                : /* no outputs */
                : /* no inputs */
                : /* clobbers */ "ah", "al");
}
```

I've put in two 'clobbers' as an example, but you'll need to set the correct list of clobbers so that the compiler knows you've overwritten register values (maybe none).

Comment: Looking at this again ... you might need to make the two ints `volatile` to prevent the compiler optimizing them away. Note sure.

Comment: @IsmaelLuceno I'm not sure what x86 assembler is supposed to look like (I mostly use it for ARM). The point of the answer is the C "asm" syntax. I've edited it to look like what some of the other answers. Is that better?

Comment: The C `asm` syntax is also wrong, it would not even compile as it is, but if you fix the syntactical details it will end up compiling non-working code (it is actually GCC's fault, but still...).

Comment: First, `asm` on variables only works for register or static variables, and the `volatile` keyword must go after `asm`

Comment: Second, GCC isn't really smart about the x86 registers, and it does the wrong thing, so you must combine `%ah` and `%al` into `%eax`.

Comment: Sigh, I probably wasn't somewhere I could test it when I wrote that. I know those things really. The intel specific stuff is explicitly an example only.

Comment: You have still one non-x86-specific problem, how do you prevent the compiler from optimizing away the unused `ah` and `al` variables?

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind GCC doesn't support 16-bit code yet, so you'll end up compiling 32-bit code in 16-bit mode, which is very inefficient but doable (it is used, for example, by Linux and SeaBIOS). It can be done with the following at the begging of each file:

```
__asm__ (".code16gcc");
```

Newer GCC versions (since 4.9 IIRC) support the `-m16` flag that does the same thing.

Also, there's no mouse driver available unless you load it previous to your kernel running `init_mouse`.

You seem to be using an API commonly available in several x86 DOS.

`asm` can take care of the register assignments, so the code can be reduced to:

```
void set_video_mode(int mode)
{
    mode &= 255;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "int $0x10"
        : "+a" (mode) /* %eax = mode & 255 => %ah = 0, %al = mode */
    );
}

void init_mouse(void)
{
    /* XXX it is really important to check the IDT entry isn't 0 */
    int tmp = 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "int $0x33"
        : "+a" (tmp) /* %eax = 0*/
        :: "ebx" /* %ebx is also clobbered by DOS mouse drivers */
    );
}
```

The `asm` statement is documented in the GCC manual, although perhaps not in enough depth and lacks x86 examples. The outputs (after first colon) have a distinctively obscure syntax, while the rest is far easier to understand (the second colon specifies the inputs and the third the clobbered registers, flags and/or memory).

The outputs must be prefixed with `=`, meaning you don't care the previous value it may have had, or `+`, meaning you want to use it as an input too. In  this context we use that instead of an input because the value is modified by the interrupt and you're not allowed to specify input registers in the clobbered list (because the compiler is forbidden from using them).